# How to include a linefeed in a string literal in bash?

Tags: bash

Is there a simpler version for the following:

```
MY_VAR=$(echo -ne "Hello\nWorld")
```

(--> something get gets along without the "echo"?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go ahead and put the newline in there.

```
MY_VAR='Hello
World'
```

Comment: This is the most portable option, since it doesn't depend on any bash extensions. Also (like the `$'...'` and `printf -v` options but unlike `$(echo ...)`), it doesn't depend on `echo` behaving in any predictable way (different versions of `echo` ... vary), and works with trailing linefeeds (`$(...)` always trims trailing linefeeds).

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can use `$'...'` to translate escape sequences:

```
$ var=$'hello\nworld'
$ echo "$var"
hello
world
```

But note that this is a nonstandard extension to shell syntax. It will work in bash, zsh, and ksh, but will not work in plain POSIX shells like dash and ash (if you try it in one of those, you'll get a variable that contains literal dollar-sign, backslash, and "n" characters).

Answer (score 1):

Another `bash` extension is to use the `-v` option with `printf` to print to a variable.

```
printf -v var 'hello\nworld'
```